# unable to rule out number "0" from the user input in python using isdigit() method

Tags: python, output

I had to create a list for the user in python which has to contain numbers between 0-10. As '0' and greater than 9 should be excluded. I had written a code using '.isdigit()' so that words are eliminated, but I am stuck with '0' elimination as the console is executing '0' too. I tried my best as a newbie.Can anyone help me out!?

```
def playerposition(): 
    p_keys= list(range(1,10))

    print('pick a position now: ')
    postn=input('choose a position between (1-9): ')
    
    while postn not in p_keys:
        while postn.isdigit()==False or postn==0:
            print('wrong input! enter again!: ')
            postn=input('choose a position between (1-9): ')
            
        print(int(postn))
        print(p_keys)
        break
playerposition()
```

Executed Output (Console):

choose a position between (1-9): hello
wrong input! enter again!:

choose a position between (1-9): 1
1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

runcell
choose a position between (1-9): 0
0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] ---> here is the probelm where 0 is also being executed by taking as an input instead of showing as ('wrong input try again! :)

sample of expected ouput:
choose a position between (1-9): 0
wrong input! enter again!:
choose a position between (1-9):

Comment: You can simplify `post.isdigit()==False` to `not post.isdigit()`.

Comment: `input()` return string and `"0"` != `0` so it can pass the check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, the following happen:

1. `p_keys` is a list of integers while `postn` is a string return by `input()`.
2. A string will not be in a list of integers so `while postn not in p_keys:` is always True and pass `postn` to next while loop.
3. `while postn.isdigit() == False or postn == 0:` successfully stop non-numeric string but it cannot stop `postn` with value `"0"` since string `"0"` is not equal to integer `0`.
4. Turning the condition from `postn == 0` to `postn == "0"` does rule out `"0"` as input, but you still miss something here. All numeric strings like `"46"`, `"82"`, `"100"` can pass the check, in fact `"1"` pass the check in your test run because it is numeric rather than it is in range of `p_keys`.

Therefore I change the condition:

```
def playerposition():
    p_keys = list(range(1,10))

    print('pick a position now: ')
    postn = input('choose a position between (1-9): ')
    # 1. not postn.isdigit() stop non-numeric string so we can confirm postn is a numeric string
    # 2. we can safely convert postn to integer and check if it is in p_keys,
    #    it will stop 0 and other numbers as they are not in p_keys 
    while not postn.isdigit() or int(postn) not in p_keys:
        print('wrong input! enter again!: ')
        postn = input('choose a position between (1-9): ')

    print(int(postn))
    print(p_keys)

playerposition()
```

Another way to do is changing `p_keys` to a list of strings:

```
def playerposition():
    p_keys = [str(i) for i in range(1,10)]
    print('pick a position now: ')
    postn = input('choose a position between (1-9): ')
    # no need to check if postn is numeric or not, words not in p_keys can be ruled out already
    while postn not in p_keys:
        print('wrong input! enter again!: ')
        postn = input('choose a position between (1-9): ')

    print(int(postn))
    print(list(range(1,10)))

playerposition()
```

Test run:

```
pick a position now:
choose a position between (1-9): hello
wrong input! enter again!:
choose a position between (1-9): 10
wrong input! enter again!:
choose a position between (1-9): 0
wrong input! enter again!:
choose a position between (1-9): 1
1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @adamkwm .Just tried executing the first code with the given corrections you have shown, it was well executed and my mistakes were learned as i'm a newbie trying to improve. ALL WENT WELL WITH YOUR CODE

Comment: @Nithin I'm a learner trying to improve too, it's good that if I can help. You can accept my answer if it solves your problem or you may ask for more info if you need.

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect:

```
 while postn.isdigit()==False or postn==0:
```

It should be

```
while postn.isdigit()==False or postn=="0":
```

Comment: Thank you @jsumskas for pointing out. Just corrected it, Thank You. #Peace...!